# Why does implicit == on map<<int,MyClass> not compile?

Tags: c++, c++11, operators

I have a strange issue defining == for one of my class. 
I simplified the code here to an example that i tested on my visual 2013;
**MyClass is defined in namespace N**

This does compile:

```
N::MyClass a, b;
bool test = a == b;
```

This too:

```
const N::MyClass a, b;
bool test = a == b;
```

**This does not compile**

```
std::map<int, N::MyClass> a, b;
bool test = a == b;
```

For your information the == operator is declared like this :

```
bool operator==(const N::MyClass & a, const N::MyClass & b);
```

here is the error I get : `error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const MyClass' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

But from what I know the map operator is defined : [map == reference on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_cmp)

**could someone explain me why this is wrong ?**

Thank you in advance.

I did not find an answer and I'm sorry if this is stupid.

**[solution]**
If I mode the operator into the namespace it works :

```
bool N::operator==(const MyClass & a, const MyClass & b);
```

**But I don't know why I need to do that, is it in the language definition ?** *(I guess yes)*

Comment: What’s with all the underscores?

Comment: How is `operator==` defined for `MyClass`?

Comment: nothing sorry, I had variables called a and b in my function, I remove this right away

Comment: Please provide more code. The implementation of `operator==` for `Arturia::WrapperLib::PresetData` for example

Comment: @Manu343726 Please don’t do edits like this. You may disagree with OP’s use of `auto` but that’s a stylistic choice, not a valid edit reason.

Comment: Ok, sorry I followed a suggestion to make it clearer but I will stop.

Comment: @KonradRudolph the reason for the edit was to fix the typo in `MyClassa`. I used that *stylistic choice* to gain the six-character minimal count to edit.

Comment: It's more than just a stylistic choice.  The OP is asking about a problem in his code.  By changing the code to something else, we are no longer looking at the code that the OP is actually asking about.

Comment: Anyway even with bool I get the same problem :)

Comment: @dzada, is your class in a namespace? Do you get the same error if you move it out of a namespace?

Comment: Whatever your problem was, the solution is not what you've described.  There is no reason a member function would work if a non-member function wouldn't.  You must have fixed the problem by accident.  I guess we'll never know.

Comment: That is the only thing I've changed. I guess that the compiler generated a non const == as all the members where EqualityComparable, but for a reason that I don't know this member == was non const. Really I agree that this should not have changed the problem from what i know of the standard, but it does so maybe it is related to the compiler

Comment: Highly doubtful.  There was a problem in your implementation, I guarantee it.

Comment: If you really have found an issue, I'm sure Microsoft would appreciate a bug report.  I know I would, since I use the product too.  At the very least, perhaps you could provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem, and I'll make the report myself.

Comment: I created a simple console app with 3 classes (one without == one with member, one with non member). And in the main I try to compare maps of these objects. Indeed I confirm that both the class with the member and non member == defined do work. So I don't know what was wrong I will do some more research

Comment: OK, I've found it. But I don't know if this is normal. My class is in a namespace N. IF I define the operator in global namespace it does not compile, If I define it in the namespace N, then it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your description, I *guess* your equality operator is not defined in the same namespace as your class. The following demonstrates the situation:

```
#include <map>

namespace foo
{
    class bar
    {
    };
}

using namespace foo;
bool operator== (bar const&, bar const&) { return true; }

int main()
{
    bar const b;
    b == b; // OK
    std::map<int, bar> mb;
    mb == mb; // ERROR
}
```

The obvious fix is to define the equality operator in the same namespace as the class. The reason it doesn't work is the two-phase name look-up in templates: when a templates is instantiated it only does second phase name look-up, i.e., it only finds functions relating to template arguments based on explicit qualification or argument dependent look-up. The equality operator isn't qualified in `std::map<K, V>` (well, it is never qualified when using operator notation to call it) and, thus, it needs to be found by argument dependent look-up.

Comment: Yes I was just writing this. :) This is the solution, but I'm not clear of why I need to do this, is it specified by the language ?

Comment: @dzada: If you look at the paragraph after my example, I'm describing the reason: the operator needs to be found by ADL as it is determined during instantiation (phase II). This is defined by the language but I don't think it is trivial to find, i.e., I'm not too keen to piece the quotes together which describe it.

Comment: Yes I did read you comment but I was indeed more wondering if it is specified by the language. And I trust you when you say it is probably specified but hard to find.

Comment: @dzada: *two-phase name look-up* is specified by the Standard. In general, to enable ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup) you should take the habit of *always* writing free-functions in the same namespace as one of their argument.

Comment: @dzada See the [the latest draft Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3691.pdf), section 3.4.2 for ADL and section 14.6.4 for 2-phase lookup of unqualified dependent names.

Answer (score 3):

Your `MyClass::operator==` needs to be marked `const`. For example:

```
bool operator ==(const MyClass&) const;
```

Note that your operator:

```
bool operator==(const MyClass & a, const MyClass & b);
```

will not work. `operator==` only takes one argument and compares `this` and the passed argument.

Unless it's not a class member operator, but a non-member one. In this case, it's correct and should work. Since it doesn't, it suggests to me that you forgot to `#include` the header file where your operator is declared.

Comment: Thank you but it is already. I added some details, about this declaration.

Comment: @dzada Oops, I forgot to actually mark it `const` in my example. Also, your `operator==` cannot possibly work. Answer updated.

Comment: Not true, operator== takes only one argument if it is a member function. If it is a global function it takes two. I'm presuming the OP's version is a global function.

Comment: How this may be because I have only non member operator ==

Comment: @dzada Hmm, it seems then that you forgot to include the header file where the operator is declared.